# net.ipv4.ip_forward reverting to 0 even though set in /etc/sysctl.conf

Tags: centos, sysctl

I set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and ran `sysctl -p` which caused it to set to `1` as expected in the output of `sysctl -a`, but sometime between last night and now something set it back to `0`.  Any thoughts on what could be doing this?  I grepped `/var/log/cron` for `forward` and for `sysctl` and didn't see anything.

Comment: if you are using **systemd** you may need to configure a
different file, eg `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`, as in [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl)

Comment: @meuh Not using systemd =(

Comment: Can't you just do `nice -19 grep -airlE 'net.ipv4.ip_forward|/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward' /` ? This will give you all the files containing mentioned file of interest.

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz Running now - we'll see what it finds.  As a side note, I'd suggest `ionice -c3` instead of `nice -19` because a search through non-compressed files tends to be more I/O intensive than CPU intensive.

Answer (score 3):

Some CentOS versions set `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to `0` again whenever the network service is restarted (with `service restart networking` for example).

To be more precise, it is set to zero in the *stop* section of the `/etc/init.d/network` script:

```bash
stop)
      [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4
      # Don't shut the network down if root is on NFS or a network
      # block device.

      # [...]

      action $"Shutting down loopback interface: " ./ifdown ifcfg-lo

      sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can edit that script and remove or change that line.

See [Red Hat Bugzilla Bug 552653](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=552653) for more information.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip.  I've edited that file to add a line which will email me should that section get called.

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't it

Comment: If you're trying to debug script, you should not email anything but simply have it `echo something &>/root/itdidrun.txt` and examine `/root/itdidrun.txt` existence and it's contents.

Comment: @siblynx What's wrong with having it email?

Comment: Because network always unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug which causes `sysctl` values to be loaded before the network is properly initialized. This causes network settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to be ignored. A solution to this may be to `procps` restart to `/etc/local.rc`, so the initialization is repeated.

The bug in question: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093

Answer (score 0):

I put logging in place to record the value of this setting every minute so then I could check `/var/log/cron` and see what might be responsible.  It looks like the reverting corresponds to a cron job for APF (Advanced Policy Firewall) running.

Here's my mini logging script in case it's helpful to anyone:

```
echo `date`" - "`sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward` >> /var/log/ip_forward_setting.log
```